# Accessing a Google Drive spreadsheet from Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I have an appengine app that needs to access a single, hard-coded spreadsheet on Google Drive.

Up until now I have been achieving this as follows:

```
SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("myapp");
service.setUserCredentials("myusername@gmail.com", "myhardcodedpassword");
```

When I tried this today with a new user, I got `InvalidCredentialsException` even though the username and password were definitely correct.  I got an email in my inbox saying suspicions sign-ins had been prevented, and there seems to be no way to enable them again.

I am also aware that hardcoding passwords in source is bad practice.

However, I have read very widely online for how to enable OAuth/OAuth2 for this, and have ended up wasting hours and hours piecing fragments of information from blogs, stackoverflow answers etc, to no avail.

Ideally the solution would involve an initial process to generate a long-lived access token, which could then be hard-coded in to the app.

I want a definitive list of steps for how to achieve this?

Comment: But there are several complete examples of oauth flow. No need to piece together from many sources. You need to *understand* the oauth process, in your case a server 3legged oauth2 flow.

Comment: I do *understand* it.  However how to hard code a server to retrieve a particular google spreadsheet is far from clear, in fact I'm not convinced it's even possible to do with OAuth.  All I can find when searching around are lots of other baffled devs.

Comment: hmm, seems you dont understand it from that comment.

Comment: Heh, go and bask in your evident superiority.

Comment: Thats not the point. The problem is that you claim to understand it when its obvious you dont. If you did you wouldnt ask such basic auestion and without any code that shows where your issue might be.

Comment: The correct answer is below, no code involved.  How does *understanding* oauth help me know which obscure parts of the Google  Cloud console to navigate?  Other blogs tell you to set an oauth consumer key, which you can only get if you have your own domain.  http://soatutorials.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/google-spreadsheet-api-connecting-with.html

Comment: Ok youre right the docs are confusing and some point to the old console steps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT: As Google have redesigned the API Console, the details of the steps below have changed - see comments**

OK here goes, step by step

1. Go to Google Cloud Console and register your project (aka application)
2. You need to note the Client ID, and Client Secret
3. Go to the OAuth Playground, click the gear icon and choose and enter your own credentials
4. You will be reminded that you need to go back to the Cloud COnsole and add the Oauth Playground as a valid callback url. So do that.
5. Do Step 1, choosing the spreadsheet scope and click authorize
6. Choose your Google account if prompted and grant auth when prompted
7. Do Step 2, Click 'Exchange auth code for tokens'
8. You will see an input box containing a **refresh token**

The refresh token is the equivalent of your long lived username/password, so this is what you'll hard code (or store someplace secure your app can retrieve it).

When you need to access Google Spreadsheets, you will call

```
POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
client_secret=************&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=1%2xxxxxxxxxx&client_id=999999999999.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

which will return you an access token

```
{
  "access_token": "ya29.yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy", 
  "token_type": "Bearer", 
  "expires_in": 3600
}
```

Put the access token into an http header for whenever you access the spreadsheet API

```
Authorization: Bearer ya29.yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

And you're done

Comment: You absolute beauty.  If you'd held on for a couple of days you'd have had a 500 point bounty.

Comment: I assume you have to obtain the client ID and Secret In the Oauth part of the credentails tab. But A Client secret doesn't seem to be given.

Comment: You need to choose "CREATE NEW CLIENT ID" -> "Web application"

Comment: Google has overhauled its cloud console UI yet again.  After creating your project, go to "API Manager", choose "Drive API", click "Enable". Choose "Credentials" on the left hand side, choose "OAuth consent screen" tab, enter a product name and click Save. Choose "Credentials" tab, "Create credentials" -> "OAuth client ID". In "Application type" choose "Web application". Then choose "Create".

Answer (score 0):

Pinoyyid has indeed provided wonderful help. I wanted to follow up with Python code that will allow access to a Personal (web-accessible) Google Drive.

This runs fine within the Google App Engine (as part of a web app) and also standalone on the desktop (assuming the Google App Engine SDK is installed on your machine [available from: [https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads]](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads%5d)).

In my case I added https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive scope during Pinyyid's process because I wanted access to all my Google Drive files.

After following Pinoyyid's instructions to get your refresh token etc., this little Python script will get a listing of all the files on your Google drive:

```
import httplib2
import datetime
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2Credentials
from apiclient.discovery import build

API_KEY = 'AIz...'       # from "Key for Server Applications" from "Public API Access" section of Google Developers Console
access_token = "ya29..." # from Piinoyyid's instructions
refresh_token = "1/V..." # from Piinoyyid's instructions
client_id = '654....apps.googleusercontent.com' # from "Client ID for web application" from "OAuth" section of Google Developers Console
client_secret = '6Cl...' # from "Client ID for web application" from "OAuth" section of Google Developers Console
token_expiry = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
token_uri = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
user_agent = 'python urllib (I reckon)'

def main():
    service = createDrive()
    dirlist = service.files().list(maxResults=30)
    print 'dirlist', dirlist
    result = dirlist.execute()
    print 'result', result

def createDrive():
    credentials = OAuth2Credentials(access_token, client_id, client_secret, refresh_token, token_expiry, token_uri, user_agent)
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)
    return build('drive', 'v2', http=http, developerKey=API_KEY)

main()
```

I'm grateful to all who have provided the steps along the way to solving this.