# access drive with access token

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-sheets, google-oauth

struggling to understand the oauth2 token and refresh token processes

ive got this code

```
    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token';
$data = array('client_id' => 'clientid', 'client_secret' => 'secret','refresh_token' => 'token','grant_type' => 'refresh_token');
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'approval_prompt'=>'force',
        'access_type'=>'offline',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

that code above gives me an access token , and i followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863104/accessing-a-google-drive-spreadsheet-from-appengine/22865286#22865286) suggested by one fellow stackoverflower, pinoyyid, BUT , im confunsed on how to correctly use the resulting access token to access drive and copy a file...

all the process ive seen usually involves `$client = new Google_Client()` and im not sure on how to use the whole POST http://..... thing, so basically i need to figure out if i use the access token i got with the code above in a new instance of google client, or i simply do a post to a url with necesary info ( which im not clear on also ) any help/clarification is appreciated guys really

EDIT #1
what i want to achieve is to allow the end user to access my drive via my webpage, to let them copy a spreadsheet in my drive , and access it via my website, to store data on the spreadsheet,the spreadsheet will always be on my drive, never on the end user

EDIT #2

code as per your posts is as follows, using the service account,,,,the files are inside that gmail account which i created on the api console a service account

```
<?php
require 'Google/autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
// Replace this with your application name.
$client->setApplicationName("TEST");
// Replace this with the service you are using.
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

// This file location should point to the private key file.
$key = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/number-privatekey.p12');
$user_to_impersonate = 'admin@testpr.com';
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
  'number@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
  array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'),  ****//this here has to be drive not drive.file
  $key,
  'notasecret',
  'http://oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer',
  $user_to_impersonate
);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}
$originFileId = "longnumber";
$copyTitle = 'copied';
$newfile = copyFile($service, $originFileId, $copyTitle);
print_r($newfile);
function copyFile($service, $originFileId, $copyTitle) 
{
  $copiedFile = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
  $copiedFile->setTitle($copyTitle);
  try {
    return $service->files->copy($originFileId, $copiedFile);
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
  return NULL;
}
?>
```

so got it working just now, ty all for your time guys really and edited my post to reflect the dang thing

Comment: One problem when starting out with OAuth is the protocol supports a variety of use cases. Eg, session vs offline access, server vs client side access, accessing the user's account vs accessing the application's account. When looking at quickstarts and code samples, it's essential that you've understood enough OAuth to know if the sample is implementing your use case, or something uselessly different. The post you linked was specifically offline access/server app/app's account. Is this also your use case? It's worth updating your question to describe what you're looking to achieve.

Comment: updated my question, to better understand what i need. Basically ill have a spreadsheet on my drive, which the end user will copy and rename , so he will later add information to that spreadsheet, for example if that end user, is allowed to create a new record for something, when he creates a new record at the same time a new spreadsheet is created on my drive to hold his information

Comment: The linked answer actually contains all of the information you need. The only bit missing is that the answer describes how to use the raw HTTP API, whereas you are using the PHP library atop the API. I've never used that library so can't help, but using the raw HTTP API is very simple and well documented on the Google Drive SDK pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to give the end user access to your drive, you have to give your application authority to make API calls on behalf of a user (in this case you) in your domain. For this you have to set up a service account and generate a p12 key in the Google Developers Console. You have to enter the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive API scope in your Admin Console as well.

Full explanation and examples can be found here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts.

To achieve this you also need the Google API's client library: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client (also mentioned in the Google manual).

Code example to let users make API calls on behalf of one of your accounts: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/aaa_oauth2_service

Comment: ive got that rig set up already, but it wont work, the spreadsheet created results invisible on my drive, and when i try to access it using the link that you can see when you `print_r($newfile);` sends you to request permission to edit, asks you to sign in to a google account then sends request permission but that request never arrives to my email or anything similar

Comment: thats why ive been trying any method ive seen around with no luck, ive got the google api client as you stated, ive got the service account setup the p12key, the spreadsheet which will be copied is already shared with the service account email ( the long one ) so when you access it you can see it , other wise you wont see it

Comment: When you connect as explained here (after configuration as explained in my post) you don't have to share your spreadsheets with the service account: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/aaa_oauth2_service. There also is no need to request an access or refresh token.

Comment: im obviously not understanding something, i just did what was on the link you posted here, and everything goes ok, at least it seems, and if i print_r($file) that was created, i get the links which send me to request access, what am i doing wrong here

Comment: sure thing mate, i just did, if we and we means you guys, are able to pull this trough im in yall debt